# Username already exists using Directive in angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to do a check on the username as soon as he entered and display an error like," this username already exists in our database"
 four steps to do that but not working

first in authService

```
  getUserByUserName(uName :string){
return this.http.get<any>(environment.baseUrl  + 'auth/login' , {
  params:new HttpParams().set('userName',uName)
})
```

}

and create directive

```
export function usernameValidatorDirective(authService:AuthService):AsyncValidatorFn{return (control: AbstractControl):Promise<ValidationErrors |null > | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
return authService.getUserByUserName(control.value).pipe(
  map(users=>{
    return users && users.length>0 ? {'userNameValidator':true}:null;
  })
)



@Directive({selector: '[userNameValidator]', providers:[{provide:NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,useExisting:UsernameValidatorDirective,multi:true}]
```

})

```
constructor(private authService:AuthService) { }
 validate(control: import("@angular/forms").AbstractControl): Promise<import("@angular/forms").ValidationErrors> | import("rxjs").Observable<import("@angular/forms").ValidationErrors> {
return this.authService.getUserByUserName(control.value).pipe(
  map(users=>{
    return users && users.length>0 ? {'userNameValidator':true}:null;
  })
)
```

}

then fill form in ts

```
      userName:['',null ,
  usernameValidatorDirective(this.authService)],
```

in html template

```
                        <div class='form-group'>
                        <label class="control-label" style="margin-right:10px; color:white">user name</label>
                        <input formControlName="userName" type="text"
                            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : registerForm.get('userName').invalid && registerForm.get('userName').touched}"
                            class="form-control" > 
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">user already exits  </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: not working sir

Comment: Did you try to debug your code and find where is not working properly?

Comment: in directive if you have another easy way you are welcome

Comment: What's the problem in your directive?whta's going wrong when you are debugging?

Comment: userNameValidator return with false value

Comment: "not working" doesn't provide enough context to help you. For example, we don't have your backend server and can't see what the response looks like.